# Nftables combine map + counters

Tags: nftables

I'm currently in the process of migrating a [firehol](https://firehol.org/) based router firewall to nftables. In general, there are no issues on the functional level, however, as I like to summarize repetitive sections with [maps](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Maps) and [sets](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets) as much as possible, I'm struggling to get [counters](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Counters) added in the same "pass". Lets take for example these dnat rules

```
table t1 {
        chain c1 {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat;

                # compact form (works)
                dnat to ip daddr map {
                        86.12.22.22 : 192.168.22.22,
                        86.12.22.23 : 192.168.22.23
                }

                # syntactically correct, but counts all dnated traffic
                counter dnat to daddr map {
                        86.12.22.22 : 192.168.22.22,
                        86.12.22.23 : 192.168.22.23
                }

                # Does not work (why?)
                ip daddr dnat to map {
                        192.168.22.22 : 86.12.22.22,
                        192.168.22.23 : 86.12.22.23
                }

                # long form (with counter, works)
                ip daddr 86.12.22.22 counter dnat to 192.168.22.22

        }

}
```

Do you know a way of somehow in-cooperate counters in a map-based rule?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer myself. It is possible using named maps:

```
table t1 {
   map one2one_dnat {
        type ipv4_addr : ipv4_addr
        flags interval
        counter
        comment "1-1 dnat"
        elements = { 
            86.12.22.22 : 192.168.22.22,
            86.12.22.23 : 192.168.22.23
        }
    }
    chain c1 {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat;
        dnat to ip daddr map @one2one_dnat
    }

}
```

Since [1.0.0](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=162939459210790&w=2) it should be possible to use "stateful expressions in maps" - however I found no way of getting this feature to work...